# Can one render a .pvd document/scene via paraviewweb or vtk.js without server side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, paraview, vtk.js

There are [examples](http://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/HttpSceneLoader.html) (especially in vtk.js that [shows](https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/blob/100db62b6cd66860bb09315eeed7dc33ea99e23f/Sources/IO/Core/HttpDataSetReader/example/index.js) [.VTP load](http://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/HttpDataSetReader.html)) that indicate that all rendering capabilities are in there, by what about file format support: can one render a .pvd scene file directly on client side with no rendering/prerendering server on the backend (say on jsfiddle)?

Or any convertion pipeline that would turn traditional paraview `.pvd` into  least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *VTK.js*, no rendering is done on the server. All the rendering is done on the client using *WebGL*.

---

If by rendering, you mean processing here are some info:

Currently, to load a VTP file with *VTK.js*, you need to pre-process it and use the [`vtkHttpDataSetReader`](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/api/IO_Core_HttpDataSetReader.html) to load the chunks created. This behavior has been implemented to handle most of the files handled by ParaView and VTK.

However, if your VTP files are not compressed (ASCII files), you could write a dedicated reader. The same behavior has been implemented for the [`vtkOBJReader`](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/api/IO_Misc_OBJReader.html). See the [OBJReader example](http://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/OBJReader.html).

**EDIT:**

The VTP file reader I mentioned in my original message has been implemented. It's named [`vtkXMLPolyDataReader`](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/api/IO_XML_XMLPolyDataReader.html). See the [GeometryViewer example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/GeometryViewer.html).